# Why still echo file not found and not delete file in dir using php?

Tags: php

I have this file in my server

```
https://www.example.com/user_img/thumb_5926887660a55.jpg
```

Then i want to delete this file using php , and i use this code.

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$user_img = "/user_img/thumb_5926887660a55.jpg";

    if (file_exists($user_img))
    {
        unlink($user_img);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "file not found";
    }
?>
```

and this code

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$user_img = "https://www.example.com/user_img/thumb_5926887660a55.jpg";

    if (file_exists($user_img))
    {
        unlink($user_img);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "file not found";
    }
?>
```

But all my code still echo file not found and not delete file in dir, how can i do ?

Comment: Start using absolute paths.

Comment: try `$user_img = "user_img/thumb_5926887660a55.jpg";` without the leading slash.

Comment: @  RiggsFolly- still echo file not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path in a URL is relative to the server's document root, you need to prepend that to the filename.

```
$user_img = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/user_img/thumb_5926887660a55.jpg";
```

Comment: Maybe there are rewrite rules, so the file is actually somewhere else. You need to find the actual location of the file on the server, and put that into `$user_img`.